# Parsing over data and extracting an element in PHP

Tags: php

```
$pf = new Petfinder('API_KEY');
$pf->setResponseFormat('json');
$petJson = $pf->pet_find(array('output'=>'basic', 'location' => '32810', 'count' => '25'));
$pet = json_decode($petJson);
foreach ($pet as $pets)
{
    print_r($pets);
}
```

I tried `var_dump($pets->pets->pet);` but that didn't work.

/* Response */

```
iso-8859-11.0stdClass Object
(
    [lastOffset] => stdClass Object
    (
        [$t] => 1
    )
    [pets] => stdClass Object
    (
        [pet] => stdClass Object
        (
            [options] => stdClass Object
            (
                [option] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => housebroken
                )
            )
            [breeds] => stdClass Object
            (
                [breed] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => Domestic Short Hair
                )
            )
            [shelterPetId] => stdClass Object()
            [status] => stdClass Object
            (
                [$t] => A
            )
            [name] => stdClass Object
            (
                [$t] => Bottle Fed Kittens
            )
            [contact] => stdClass Object
            (
                [email] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => catboutcolonies@yahoo.com
                )    
                [zip] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => 32810
                )    
                [city] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => Orlando
                )
                [fax] => stdClass Object()
                [name] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => Lori Lewis
                )
                [address1] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => P.O.Box 607082
                )
                [phone] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [$t] => 407-953-0297
                )
            )
            [description] => stdClass Object
            (
                [$t] =>
            )
            [sex] => stdClass Object
            (
                [$t] => F
            )
            [media] => stdClass Object
            (
                [photos] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [photo] => Array
                    (
                        [0] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@size] => x
                            [$t] => http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/US/FL/FL1155/26769037/FL1155.26769037-1-x.jpg
                            [@id] => 1
                        )
                        [2] => stdClass Object
                        (
                            [@size] => t
                            [$t] => http://photos.petfinder.com/photos/US/FL/FL1155/26769037/FL1155.26769037-3-t.jpg
                            [@id] => 3
                        )
                    )
                )
            )
            [id] => stdClass Object
            (
                [$t] => 26769037
            )
            [animal] => stdClass Object
            (
                [$t] => Cat
            )
        )
    )
    [header] => stdClass Object
    (
        [timestamp] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$t] => 2013-08-13T05:54:46Z
        )
        [status] => stdClass Object
        (
            [message] => stdClass Object()
            [code] => stdClass Object
            (
                [$t] => 100
            )
        )
        [version] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$t] => 0.1
        )
    )
    [@xsi: noNamespaceSchemaLocation] = > http: //api.petfinder.com/schemas/0.9/petfinder.xsd
)
```

I'm just trying to extract one element such as the breed, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: you have this in your response `iso-8859-11.0`. try to remove it

Comment: this is an `OBJECT` response not the `JSON`

Comment: Any suggestions on how to go about removing the iso-8859-11.0 from the object?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I was able to parse the breed.

```
    var_dump($pet->petfinder->pets->pet->breeds->breed)
```

Response

```
   array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#25 (1) { ["$t"]=> string(19) "Domestic Short Hair" }          [1]=> object(stdClass)#26 (1) { ["$t"]=> string(36) "Domestic Short Hair -Gray And White" } }
```

Answer (score 1):

to get Breed you would need to do the following.

```
$pf = new Petfinder('API_KEY');
$pf->setResponseFormat('json');
$petJson = $pf->pet_find(array('output'=>'basic', 'location' => '32810', 'count' => '25'));
$pet = json_decode($petJson);
```

var dump

```
var_dump($pet->pets->pet->breeds->breed);
```

Comment: For some reason this solution is not working, even though I know it's the right code to extract the breed.

Comment: what do you get when you print_R($pet)?

Comment: When I print_R($pet) I get back the entire object like above, but when I try var_dump($pet->pets->pet->breeds->breed); I get back Undefined property: stdClass::$pets.

Answer (score 0):

you can convert this object to array and use array functions, try this code to convert.

```
if (is_object($pets)) {
    $pets_arr = get_object_vars($pets);
    var_dump($pets_arr);
}
```

Comment: I added the snippet of code above, and it got rid of the iso-8859-11.0. Thanks for the help!